# How to determine the value of the 3 channel in RGB or BGR

Tags: c++, opencv

This is the image that i need to detect

[image]

```
//  cdst is the image
//    This is the code which i want to know what are the values in a certain pixel but the code below only detects the first then the 2nd and 3rd is equal to 0 

    void dec()
    {
        Mat em;
        cdst="path of the image";

        //this is the value of BGR per color that i wish to check
        Vec3f red(0, 0, 255);
        Vec3f blue(255, 0, 0);
        Vec3f green(0, 128, 0);
        Vec3f yellow(0, 255, 255);
        Vec3f marron(0, 0,128);
        Vec3f pink(147, 20, 255);
        Vec3f indigo(130, 0, 75);
        Vec3f midblue(112, 25, 25);
        Vec3f magenta(139, 0, 139);
        //em will hold the cdst image
        em=cdst;
        //for loop to determine what are the colors
        for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++)
        {
            int x = l[i][0];
            int y = l[i][1];
            cout << x << " " << y<<endl;
            Vec3f px = em.at<uchar>(y,x);

           //Im trying to print all color of the 3 channels
           //But it only the first on has a value then the second and third is 0
            cout << px.val[0] << " " << px.val[1] << " "<<px.val[2]<<endl;
            if (px == pink)
            {
                cout<<"A";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if each channel is 8 bit use .at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x) instead of .at<uchar>(y,x) (which would be a single 8 bit channel). In addition change all your Vec3f to Vec3b. Vec3f means to be a pixel of 3 float channels.

Comment: Try this by replacing uchar to cv;;Vec3b.  Vec3f px = em.at<Vec3b>(y,x);

Comment: what is the difference of 3b and 3f?

Comment: @Micka i tried chaging the uchar to Vec3b, when i printed the px.val[0-2] the output are some weird symbols, may i ask why is that?

Comment: because characters are interpreted as symbols whwn printing. If variable pixel is a Vec3b try either 'cout << pixel << endl;' or 'cout << (int) pixel[0] << endl;' (to print a single channel)

Comment: @Micka i tried print it with the (int) and it work, may i ask another question how can i check the value of the obtained pixel with the list of Vec3b colors?

Comment: For exact equivalence you can do this: for each vec3b val in your list: if (pixelVec3b == listItemVec3b) perform some action;

Comment: for near equivalence you can do: if(cv::norm(pixelVec-listVec) < someThreshold) perform some action;

Comment: there are some colors that have merge or mixed together, how can i specify those mixed color to be a certain color?

Comment: an example is the color between Green and Pink, when zooming in the image there would be a different intensity value of Green or pink and there are chances that 2 color would mix

Comment: when i displayed the pixel value there was never a match pixel to the list about for each color. may i ask some suggestions on how i can determin what color that is?

Comment: i notice when i zoomed the image there are some colors that have mix to create a new color, and some colors that is being lighter. so what i want is to stop mixing the color and stop the colors on being lighter if possible, i want the color to be the pure color that i have set

Answer (score 0):

How about try this code?

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(){

    Mat em(100, 100, CV_8UC3, Scalar::all(0));
    rectangle(em, Rect(30, 30, 10, 10), Scalar(147, 20, 255), -1);

    imshow("em", em);
    waitKey(1);

    Vec3b pink(147,20,255);
    for (int i = 0; i < em.rows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < em.cols; j++){
            Vec3b px = em.at<Vec3b>(i, j);
            cout << px << endl;
            if (px == pink){
                cout << "A" ;

            }
        }
    }

    waitKey(0);
    destroyAllWindows();
    return 0;
}
```